# Reset controller properties as you leave the route ember.js

Tags: javascript, ember.js, router

I have some controller properties in the index controller. I am wondering how I can change the value of these properties when the user is changing the route. Since the index has an outlet, the index route properties are still present on a different route, which is what I want.

Basically when the route changes, I want to reset properties of the index controller. How do I do that?

Comment: Let me just make sure I fully understand you, you're trying to access properties of one controller from another controller?  But it sounds like you are trying to access a controller from a route.  That sounds like you might get yourself into trouble when someone doesn't visit that route first.

Comment: Basically when the route changes, I want to reset properties of the index controller. How do I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

from a different route:

```
var controller = this.controllerFor('index');
controller.set('foo', 'bar');
```

from a different controller:

```
App.FooController = Em.Object.extend({
  needs:'index',
  someFunc: function(){
    var controller = this.get('controllers.index');
    controller.set('foo', 'bar');
  }
});
```

on transition

```
App.IndexRoute = Em.Route.extend({
  actions: {
    willTransition: function(){
      this.controller.set('foo', 'bar');
    }
  }
});
```